# Are there contiguous sequences of prime numbers of length $k$ which are convex (similarly, concave) for every $k\in\mathbb{N}?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, prime-gaps

Does the sequence of prime numbers contain contiguous subsequences of length $k$ which are strictly convex (similarly, strictly concave), for every $k\in\mathbb{N}?$
For example,

$$ 17, 19, 23, 29 $$

is contiguous and strictly convex with $k=4.$

and

$$61, 67, 71, 73$$

is contiguous and strictly concave with $k=4.$

I'm sure we can find sequences of contiguous primes with $k=5,6$ i.e. of length $5$ or $6$ for each strictly concave and strictly convex. But can we find $k=$ arbitrarily large for both strictly concave (and strictly convex)?

If we add $1$ to every member of the Thue-Morse sequence and call this sequence $(t_n),$ and define $x_1=1, x_{k+1} = x_k + t_k.$ Then then looking at the sequence $(x_n)$ shows that you can even have strictly increasing sequences of positive integers which have positive density and have a cap (upper bound) on $k,$ the longest contiguous strictly concave/convex subsequence of $(x_n),$ (which is $k=3$ due to the fact the T-M is cube-free). So basically, the density of the primes $p_n$ as $n\to\infty$ doesn't help us answer the above question. It is true, however, that the PNT tells us that the size of the largest prime gap $\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty.$ I'm not sure this helps either though.

Comment: Doesn't convexity here simply mean that the difference between consecutive primes increases in each step? Then any convex sequenceof primes can be extended arbitrarily far.

Comment: @nickgard I agree, and have amended the question accordingly.

Comment: @quarague yes that's what it means. Can you prove it?

Comment: I doubt anything can be proved one way or another about a question like this.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You mean, it is likely an open problem? [Although that wouldn't mean it cannot be proved].

Comment: I mean it's likely a wide-open problem, far beyond our current capabilities.

Comment: Second differences of the primes are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A036263 and the first 100,000 terms are given at https://oeis.org/A036263/b036263.txt – unfortunately, no references to the literature are given. What you are looking for is long strings with the same sign. Just eyeballing it, I see several strings of length three (corresponding to a strictly concave or convex string of length five), and entries 282 to 285 are $-2,-8,-2,-2$ so a string of six primes. I found nothing longer out to entry 1000.

Comment: A discussion of second differences of primes on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322786/second-differences-of-primes-pattern also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206581/second-differences-of-primes-determined-by-increasing-first-differences-every-p

Comment: I thought you only want a sequence of prime numbers and then oen can easily extend sequences. If you want a sequence of primes that are consequtive, meaning there is no other prime in between then this is way harder and as others have said probably currently unknown and not within reach.

Comment: The string of six consecutive primes from my earlier comment is $$1831\ 1847\ 1861\ 1867\ 1871\ 1873$$

Comment: Relevant: https://oeis.org/A158939 for increasing gaps and https://oeis.org/A158940 for decreasing gaps.